# How we can execute a javascript function and get a return value in our android application?

Tags: javascript, android, return

How we can execute a javascript function and get a return value in our android appplication ?

We want to execute a javascript on a button press event, we need to pass parameters to the script and get return values, So we are using "WebChromeClient" to implement this, 
But we got Exception is "SyntaxError: Parse error at undefined:1"

Following is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class FirstTab extends Activity 
{


    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.regis);

            try{

                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
                String customHtml = "<html><head><title>iSales</title><script type=\"text/javascript\"> function fieldsOnDelete(){ var x=123; return \"JIJO\"; } </script></head><body>hi</body></html>";
                webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html","UTF-8");  

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                     Log.v("JAC LOG",e.toString());
                }

        }
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 try{
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(javascript:fieldsOnDelete())");
                 }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     Log.v("JAC LOG",e.toString());

                 }
              } 
             });
    }


    final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {

        Log.v("LogTag", message);
          result.confirm();
          return true;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: [refer this](https://github.com/scottagarman/Android-JavaScript-Interface-Example)may it helps to solve your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use  `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:checkName");` to call the method...

Then you can use `addJavascriptInterface()` to add a Java object to the Javascript environment. Have your Java script call a method on that Java object to supply its "return value".

EDIT1: Or you can use following hack:

Add this Client to your WebView:

```
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            Log.d("LogTag", message);
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now in your java script call do:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(functionThatReturnsSomething)");
```

Now in the onJsAlert call "`message`" will contain the returned value.

Edit2:

So it does not work if we call javascript method just after call to load the URL since the page loads take time. So I created a test program to test that...

Following is my html file (named test.html) store in the assets folder:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
    function fieldsOnDelete(message) {
        alert("i am called with " + message);
        window.myjava.returnValue(message + " JIJO");
    }
</script>
<title>iSales android</title>


</head>
<body></body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my java class that would get that i would add to java script as interface and it would receive the return value:

```
public class MyJS {

    public void returnValue(String string){
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), string);
    }

}
```

And following is my activity class:

```
public class CheckWebView extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_web_view);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber,
                    String sourceID) {
                super.onConsoleMessage(message, lineNumber, sourceID);
                Log.d(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "message " + message
                        + "   :::line number " + lineNumber + "   :::source id "
                        + sourceID);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage.message(),
                        consoleMessage.lineNumber(), consoleMessage.sourceId());

                Log.d(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "message::::: "
                        + consoleMessage.message());

                return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
            }
        });

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJS(), "myjava");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_check_web_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:fieldsOnDelete('name');");
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

The key here is that there should be some time interval between the call to load html file from assets folder and the call to `javascript:method`. Here I am calling it from `onOptionsItemSelected` and it is working fine.. if I move the          `webView.loadUrl("javascript:fieldsOnDelete('name');");` to the end of the onCreate() method the it shows the error that it can not find `fieldsOnDelete()` method...

Hope it Helps...

EDIT3:

Replace following in your code

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(javascript:fieldsOnDelete())");
```

with

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(fieldsOnDelete())");
```

and try...

Comment: we have no url, we are saving our javascript in a string variable. eg: String customHtml = "<html><head><title>iSales</title><script type=\"text/javascript\">function fieldsOnDelete(){ return \"JIJO\"; }</script></head><body></body></html>";
            
webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");       when we excute we got a parse error.

Comment: try calling `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:checkName");` after calling the `webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

Comment: We tried webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(javascript:fieldsOnDelete())"); for get return value, but we got "SyntaxError: Parse error at undefined:1" message in the web console Tag, but its work fine for webView.loadUrl("javascript:var x=123;alert(x)");

Comment: it was a silly timing issue with web view... I was able to run it.. updating answer in 5 minutes...

Comment: already posted the working demo code in the answer... have you tried that?

Comment: very very thanks for your help, our problem is, the javascript comming from the remote server so we cant edit that, So we trying to implement with onJsAlert() method in WebChromeClient, but it shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : at null:1" when call webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(javascript:fieldsOnDelete())");

Comment: we are calling String customHtml = "<html><head><title>jijo</title><script type=\"text/javascript\"> function fieldsOnDelete(){ var x=123; return \"JIJO\"; } </script></head><body>hi</body></html>";
webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html","UTF-8"); in onCreate()method and   webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(javascript:fieldsOnDelete())"); in a button onClick() , So we think there is no timing issue, can u please check the script

Comment: can you edit the original question and post this code you that I can try it out at my end...

Comment: Thank for your valuable time, Now I update the code in the question, can you please check

Comment: Sorry I can't vote now, I have only one reputation.  One more doubt is, I want to get the return value in the same line we call webView.loadUrl() for further operation, Now we got that in onJsAlert() method after the excution of onClick() event ,How we can get that in onClick() method, please help...

Comment: define a global variable and assign the value you get in the `onJsAlert()` message parameter and use that global variable in the `onClick()` method after the call to `loadUrl()`.  Please accept the answer....

Comment: But onJsAlert() method will execute after the execution of onClick(), Is there any way to execute onJsAlert() when we call webView.loadUrl().

Comment: you could use the approach i defined in edit 2 if you can somehow modify the java script....

Comment: Thanks, We can't edit javascript because that comming from remote server, also we want to execute 3-4 javascripts consecutively.

Answer (score 4):

In Android KitKat there is a new method evaluateJavascript that has a callback for a return value. The callback returns a JSON value, object or array depending on what you return.

```
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // In KitKat+ you should use the evaluateJavascript method
            mWebView.evaluateJavascript(javascript, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(s));

                    // Must set lenient to parse single values
                    reader.setLenient(true);

                    try {
                        if(reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
                            if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
                                String msg = reader.nextString();
                                if(msg != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "MainActivity: IOException", e);
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // NOOP
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

You can see a full example here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/jsinterface-example